# Android Camera Degree Range

Tags: android, camera, zooming

Let's say I 've opened the camera and set the zoom level to any desired value. How can I calculate the horizontal degree range of the current focus?

I want to use this for augmented reality purposes. I can supposedly get the zoom ratios with `getZoomRatios()`, but how do I convert them to the degree range? What's the **`zoom 0`** degree range?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Is [getHorizontalViewAngle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getHorizontalViewAngle%28%29) the method you want?

Comment: I'm not sure. It returns the same value no matter the current zoom level.

Comment: I see. I'm guessing that's the value for 1x zoom; call it T. At 2x zoom, the view angle ought to be 2*atan(tan(T/2)/2). For zoom Z it should be 2*atan(tan(T/2)/Z). Zoom 0 range would theoretically be 180 degrees, I guess.